# ASN1_TIME wrong on Windows CE 6.0

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, windows-ce, x509

I'm using OpenSSL on Windows 7 and Windows Embedded CE6.0 (ARMV4I-platform).

For this I compiled OpenSSL on my own originally for version 0.9.8w for Windows 7 and my ARMV4I-platform. Executing `openssl.exe` works fine on both machines.

I compile [mkcert.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/x509/mkcert.c) which uses the `libeay32.dll` that I built previously.

On my Windows 7 machine everything works fine and the certificate is issued correctly. But on the ARMV4I-device I notice that the dates (`X509_get_notBefore(x)` and `X509_get_notAfter(x)`) are wrong:

- Windows 7 - `X509_get_notBefore(x)` the value is `150710093249Z`
- CE 6.0 - `X509_get_notBefore(x)` the value `39150810093249Z`

And the difference is always the value `39000100000000`. This leads to the difference in validity on Windows CE which is now `Aug  10 09:32:49 3915 GMT` instead of `Jul  10 09:32:49 2015 GMT`.

Later on I compiled OpenSSL 1.0.2c and executed the same code but the problem still occurs.

Do you know why this happens and how it can be fixed?

(One possible fix might be to adjust the ASN1_TIME on Windows CE manually:

```c
#ifdef UNDER_CE
    X509_gmtime_adj(notBefore,-39000100000000);
    X509_gmtime_adj(notAfter,-39000100000000);
#endif
```

This would then need to happen in various steps as `X509_gmtime_adj()` accepts as second parameter only values of type long:

```c
ASN1_TIME *X509_gmtime_adj(ASN1_TIME *s, long adj);
```

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Is the clock set correctly on the Windows CE device?

Comment: Thank for the hint. Yes, the clock is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved with the following fix:
[github commit](https://github.com/darius-kim/wcecompat/commit/1acd39ae080a18182d7bfe2736fecc3fa4503739)